# How to join conditionally and get data from the join table?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two tables, `Product` and `ProductNewsletter`. A product can have many `product_newsletters`, thus this in rails is a `has_many` relationship on the side of the products, and `belongs_to` on the product_newsletter side, with a product_id. The tables kind of look like this:

```
products
id title... etc

product_newsletters
id product_id date
```

I'd like to get the products that have a product_newsletter in a range of dates, and also select the date from the found product_newsletter in the query. So if a product has two product_newsletter, with dates 11-03-2018, 20-03-2018 and 04-04-2018, querying with dates between 01-03-2018 and 30-01-03-2018 should display this product twice, once with 11-03-2018, and another with 20-03-2018. At first I tried this join with a subquery:

```
SELECT *
     , news.date AS newsletter_date 
  FROM products 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT newsletter_products.* 
         FROM newsletter_products 
        WHERE newsletters.date BETWEEN '2018-01-03' AND '2018-01-20'
     ) news 
    ON  products.id = news.product_id
```

But this join results in product with an id that is the same of those newsletters in the subquery, not the ones in `product_id` as I expected from the subquery. I'm using ruby on rails and Mysql. My idea is to use the results of this query to simply do a ruby `products.group_by(&:newsletter_date)` and end up with a nice hash with the dates as keys and products as values, without extra queries or filtering per each date, which is my current implementation.

Comment: That query looks okay. I wouldn't use a subquery though, but just a simple join on the table directly, with a where clause specifying the date rage. I don't really understand your problem description, but I think it's related to the fact that you select `*`, which means all columns from both tables (the products table and the subquery/derived table. I would select only the exact columns you want. If you want a column from both tables with the same same name, you can provide an alias for that column (for instance `products.id as product_id, news.id as news_id`).

Comment: A great tip for a better life is NEVER use `SELECT *`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following will provide you expected output,

```
Product.joins(:product_newsletters).where(product_newsletters: { date: ['19-01-2013'.to_datetime..'19-02-2013'.to_datetime] })
```

If 2 product_newsletters objects falls in range of date and both have same product_id, still for above query you will get `2 counts` for same product id.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using this as a base, ended up splitting the product_newsletters query and adding the extra select clause at the end so I can do a ruby `group_by` later. So at the end it is something like: `Product.joins(:newsletter_products).merge(newsletter_products).
      select('products.*, newsletter_products.date AS newsletter_product_date')` This actually renders something similar to Gordon's generic sql answer, marking this as the accepted one but both are valid answers.

Answer (score 2):

You should write the query like this:

```
SELECT p.*, n.date AS newsletter_date
FROM products p INNER JOIN 
     newsletter_products np
     ON p.id = n.product_id
WHERE np.date BETWEEN '2018-01-03' AND '2018-01-20';
```

Notes:

- Don't use `select *`.  You will get the newletter date twice.
- The subquery is unnecessary and might impede optimization.
- Use table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.
- I don't like `between` with dates, but that is the logic you are doing.  It is safe when `date` has no time component.